# Count word in text column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, cpu-word, operand

This question is about MySQL Query.
I have three tables:

1. brand (consists of: text)
2. englishkeyword (consists of ID, word)
3. englishkeywordmodel (consists of: ID, score)

I want to count how many words in 'text' with the word which is already determined in 'word'. Then the result is stored in 'score'. This is my code:

```
UPDATE englishkeywordmodel
SET score=(SELECT COUNT(*)FROM brand WHERE text LIKE (SELECT word FROM englishkeyword WHERE ID=2 LIKE ('%', word, '%')))
WHERE ID=2;
```

I got this error:

## 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

I say many thanks for answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LIMIT` because Your subquery is selecting two or more columns

```
SELECT word FROM englishkeyword WHERE ID=2 AND Column LIKE
CONCAT('%', word ,'%')  limit 1
```

Comment: wait, sorry, I make mistake with my question. I have made editing. btw, I still got error with that query

Comment: WHERE ID=2 LIKE ('%', word, '%') this is  not valid

Comment: WHERE ID=2 **AND Column** LIKE ('%', word, '%')  change this

Comment: SELECT word FROM englishkeyword WHERE ID=2 AND Column LIKE
CONCAT('%', word ,'%')  limit 1 try this

Comment: it's my pleasure :)- @caknizar

Comment: hmm I have additional question related to this posting: is that possible if I do for some ID in one query? suppose I have 10 ID so how to query in a time?

Comment: Use **where id IN (1,2,3,4,5...)** @caknizar

Comment: it works but from my observation the counted word is only first ID, so the ID value after is same with first ID. eg. ID 1 is counted 4, then 2,3,4,5 = 4 (whereas isn't)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94716/discussion-between-cak-nizar-and-rahautos).